# innerHTML does not dynamically update nor display on PHP page - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have managed to dynamically display the sum of 6 line-cost DOM elements from a php file. Unfortunately, when trying to calculate the delivery charge, my JavaScript methods regarding to the deliveryCharge implementation fails to display anything on the page. With the sub-total methods working and displaying perfectly, I tried to troubleshoot the problem by providing innerHTML with a constant value of both a string and an int- both times yielded nothing to be displayed on screen.

I have displayed both the working part of the sub-total calculation method as well as the non-working part of the delivery-charge calculation. Would the problem lie within an incorrect way of using innerHTML, be a calculation error or a different error entirely?

```
  function calcST(){
  var i;
  var sum = 0; // initialize the sum
  let p = document.getElementsByTagName("line_cost");

  for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(Number(p[i].innerHTML))) {
       sum = Number(sum + Number(p[i].innerHTML)); // p[i].innerHTML gives you the value
    }

  }

  setST(sum, "sub_total");
}


function setST(sum, item_id){
  let i = document.getElementById(item_id);
  i.innerHTML = sum;
  calcDelivCharge();
}


function getST() {
  let i = document.getElementById("sub_total");
  let v = i.innerHTML;
  return v;
}


function calcDelivCharge(){

  var delCharge;
  var e = getST();

  if(e < 100){
    delcharge = e*0.10
  }else{
    delcharge = 0;
  }

  setDelivCharge("delivery_charge", delCharge);
}

function setDelivCharge(item_id, delCharge){
  let i = document.getElementById(item_id);
  i.innerHTML = delCharge;
  calculateTAX();
}


function getDelivCharge() {
  let i = document.getElementById("delivery_charge");
  let v = i.innerHTML;
  return v;
}
```

Comment: Did you try starting the browsers javascript debugger and debugging your code F12

Comment: I managed to open the debugger, I found an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null` under the `getST()` method on the line: `let v = i.innerHTML;`

Comment: change `let i = document.getElementById("sub-total");` to `let i = document.getElementById("sub_total");`

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, I have fixed this and I am still having 'undefined' being displayed under delivery-charge. I will edit my code to display the correct variable names.

Comment: I see this in your code: ```document.getElementsByTagName("line_cost")```.  If you're using custom HTML elements like ```<line_cost>30</line_cost>``` it would be helpful for you to share your HTML too.

Comment: @JonathanRys I am using someone else's HTML code for practice so unfortunately I am unable to share this. The only problem lies with the delivery charge variable and I do not think there is a problem with the elements. The reason I say this is due to the sub-total variable("v") working perfectly on the HTML file.

Comment: Do you have ```<div><line_cost>30</line_cost><line_cost>40</line_cost>...</div>``` or something more like this: ```<line_cost><div>30</div><div>40</div>...</line_cost>```

Comment: And what does ```calculateTAX()``` do?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find that the DOM was not ready loading before the getST() method was called. This can be fixed with the following code:

```
if(document.getElementById("sub_total") != null){
    let i = document.getElementById("sub_total");
    let v = i.innerHTML;
    return v;
  }
```

Unfortunately, delivery-charge is seen as 'unidentified'. Why does this appear when the getST() method is altered?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're HTML is like

```
<line_cost>
    <div>30</div>
    <div>40</div>
    ...
</line_cost>
```

You can do this:

```js
function calcSubtotal() {

  const costs = document.querySelector("line_cost").children;
  let sum = 0;
  
  for( let i = 0 ; i < costs.length ; i ++) {
    sum += parseInt(costs[i].innerHTML);
  }
  
  setST(sum, "sub_total");
}

// Subtotal getter and setter
function setST(sum, item_id) {
  document.getElementById(item_id).innerHTML = sum.toFixed(2);
  calcDeliveryCharge();
}

function getSubTotal() {
  return document.getElementById("sub_total").innerHTML;
}

function calcDeliveryCharge() {
  const subTotal = getSubTotal();
  setDeliveryCharge("delivery_charge", subTotal < 100 ? subTotal * 0.10 : 0);
}

function setDeliveryCharge(item_id, deliveryCharge){
  document.getElementById(item_id).innerHTML = deliveryCharge.toFixed(2);
  //calculateTAX();
}

function getDeliveryCharge() {
  return document.getElementById("delivery_charge").innerHTML;
}

calcSubtotal();
calcDeliveryCharge();
```

```html
<line_cost>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>20</div>
</line_cost>
<br/>
<div>
  <span>Sub Total: $
    <span id="sub_total"></span>
  </span>
  <br/>
  <span>Delivery Charge: $
    <span id="delivery_charge"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Otherwise, if you have:

```
<div>
    <line_cost>30</line_cost>
    <line_cost>40</line_cost>
    ...
</div>
```

Then do this:

```js
function calcSubtotal() {
  const costs = document.querySelectorAll("line_cost");
  let sum = 0 
  
  for( let i = 0 ; i < costs.length ; i ++) {
    sum += parseFloat(costs[i].innerHTML);
  }
  
  setST(sum, "sub_total");
}

// Subtotal getter and setter
function setST(sum, item_id) {
  document.getElementById(item_id).innerHTML = sum.toFixed(2);
  calcDeliveryCharge();
}

function getSubTotal() {
  return document.getElementById("sub_total").innerHTML;
}

function calcDeliveryCharge() {
  const subTotal = getSubTotal();
  setDeliveryCharge("delivery_charge", subTotal < 100 ? subTotal * 0.10 : 0);
}

function setDeliveryCharge(item_id, deliveryCharge){
  document.getElementById(item_id).innerHTML = deliveryCharge.toFixed(2);
  //calculateTAX();
}

function getDeliveryCharge() {
  return document.getElementById("delivery_charge").innerHTML;
}

calcSubtotal();
calcDeliveryCharge();
```

```css
line_cost {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <line_cost>25</line_cost>
  <line_cost>34</line_cost>
  <line_cost>43</line_cost>
  <line_cost>250</line_cost>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <span>Sub Total: $
    <span id="sub_total"></span>
  </span>
  <br/>
  <span>Delivery Charge: $
    <span id="delivery_charge"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I managed to get it working. I seem to get NaN with both Number and ParseFloat on the for-loop in the calcSubtotal() method. The fix for this is having a decision statement: `if (!isNaN(Number(costs[i].innerHTML))) {` while summing the costs in the for loop